# Blog page Server error 500 with sticky post loop in query.php

Tags: wordpress, foreach, blogs

Using sticky post on site near about 5000 sticky post i have.

In wp-includes/query.php here i have bellow snippet code.on line 3748 to 3760.If i comment this code the blog page work properly. if uncomment this blog page gives 500 error but all sites work fine except blog page.

So can any body will tell me why this happening and how to resolve it .

I have try with disabling all plugins,changed the theme , htaccess. but not worked for me.so an any one tell me how do solve this issue.

```
// Fetch sticky posts that weren't in the query results
            if ( !empty($sticky_posts) ) {
                $stickies = get_posts( array(
                    'post__in' => $sticky_posts,
                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'nopaging' => true
                ) );

                foreach ( $stickies as $sticky_post ) {
                    array_splice( $this->posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array( $sticky_post ) );
                    $sticky_offset++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Go check the server’s error log. (And isn’t the feature of making posts “sticky” supposed to highlight the _occasional_, important post? Can’t really see that making sense for 50k posts …)

Comment: @CBroe i am runing the news paper site i have post more than 40 k i have sticky near about 5k my mistake i have updated in in quetion.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after removing unwanted sticky posts.Now i am using using only 10 to 20 sticky posts.If now i want to set new sticky post i am removing the old sticky post before setting a new posts as sticky posts. 
i was having more than 5000 k sticky posts thats why blog page throwing server error 500 and or max time out errors.